# JSch addIdentity

Tags: java, ssh, ssh-key

Скажите пожалуйста, как сгенерировать файл под jsch, я пробовал с помощью PuttyGen, но `addIdentity` вылетает с `exception` с сообщением, что файл-ключ "не правильный"?

```
String sshKeyFile = "ssh-key.pem";

JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.addIdentity(sshKeyFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Пример подключения по `SSH` с логином/паролем

Пример кода `Java`, позволяющий выполнить любую команду на удаленном компьютере по протоколу `SSH` из программы `Java`:

```
package cabbott.net;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SSHManager {
    private static final Logger LOGGER =
            Logger.getLogger(SSHManager.class.getName());
    private JSch jschSSHChannel;
    private String strUserName;
    private String strConnectionIP;
    private int intConnectionPort;
    private String strPassword;
    private Session sesConnection;
    private int intTimeOut;

    private void doCommonConstructorActions(String userName,
                                            String password, String connectionIP, String knownHostsFileName) {
        jschSSHChannel = new JSch();

        try {
            jschSSHChannel.setKnownHosts(knownHostsFileName);
        } catch (JSchException jschX) {
            logError(jschX.getMessage());
        }

        strUserName = userName;
        strPassword = password;
        strConnectionIP = connectionIP;
    }

    public SSHManager(String userName, String password,
                      String connectionIP, String knownHostsFileName) {
        doCommonConstructorActions(userName, password,
                connectionIP, knownHostsFileName);
        intConnectionPort = 22;
        intTimeOut = 60000;
    }

    public SSHManager(String userName, String password, String connectionIP,
                      String knownHostsFileName, int connectionPort) {
        doCommonConstructorActions(userName, password, connectionIP,
                knownHostsFileName);
        intConnectionPort = connectionPort;
        intTimeOut = 60000;
    }

    public SSHManager(String userName, String password, String connectionIP,
                      String knownHostsFileName, int connectionPort, int timeOutMilliseconds) {
        doCommonConstructorActions(userName, password, connectionIP,
                knownHostsFileName);
        intConnectionPort = connectionPort;
        intTimeOut = timeOutMilliseconds;
    }

    public String connect() {
        String errorMessage = null;

        try {
            sesConnection = jschSSHChannel.getSession(strUserName,
                    strConnectionIP, intConnectionPort);
            sesConnection.setPassword(strPassword);
            // UNCOMMENT THIS FOR TESTING PURPOSES, BUT DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION
            // sesConnection.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            sesConnection.connect(intTimeOut);
        } catch (JSchException jschX) {
            errorMessage = jschX.getMessage();
        }

        return errorMessage;
    }

    private String logError(String errorMessage) {
        if (errorMessage != null) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "{0}:{1} - {2}",
                    new Object[]{strConnectionIP, intConnectionPort, errorMessage});
        }

        return errorMessage;
    }

    private String logWarning(String warnMessage) {
        if (warnMessage != null) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "{0}:{1} - {2}",
                    new Object[]{strConnectionIP, intConnectionPort, warnMessage});
        }

        return warnMessage;
    }

    public String sendCommand(String command) {
        StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            Channel channel = sesConnection.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
            InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            int readByte = commandOutput.read();

            while (readByte != 0xffffffff) {
                outputBuffer.append((char) readByte);
                readByte = commandOutput.read();
            }

            channel.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException ioX) {
            logWarning(ioX.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (JSchException jschX) {
            logWarning(jschX.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return outputBuffer.toString();
    }

    public void close() {
        sesConnection.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Для запуска:

```
@Test
public void testSendCommand() {
    System.out.println("sendCommand");

    /**
     * YOU MUST CHANGE THE FOLLOWING
     * FILE_NAME: A FILE IN THE DIRECTORY
     * USER: LOGIN USER NAME
     * PASSWORD: PASSWORD FOR THAT USER
     * HOST: IP ADDRESS OF THE SSH SERVER
     **/
    String command = "ls FILE_NAME";
    String userName = "USER";
    String password = "PASSWORD";
    String connectionIP = "HOST";
    SSHManager instance = new SSHManager(userName, password, connectionIP, "");
    String errorMessage = instance.connect();

    if (errorMessage != null) {
        System.out.println(errorMessage);
        fail();
    }

    String expResult = "FILE_NAME\n";
    // call sendCommand for each command and the output 
    //(without prompts) is returned
    String result = instance.sendCommand(command);
    // close only after all commands are sent
    instance.close();
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

---

Оригинал: [Run a command over SSH with JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11902536/8280225)